# Json Schema oneOf not giving correct custom error when the required fields are not passed

Tags: json

I have json schema as below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "c": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "d": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "not": {
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "required": [
          "a",
          "b"
        ],
        "errorMessage": "either of a or b is mandatory"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here exactly one of a or b is mandatory. If none of them is passed or both are passed it should give an error message

When I am passing both a and b with optional parameters c and d it's giving correct error message as below :
Request:

```
{
    "a": "67",
    "b": "52",
    "c": "test",
    "d": "123"
}
```

Response:

`"either of a or b is mandatory"`

Also when I am passing exactly one of a or b with c and d , getting success and correct output
Request:

```
{
    "b": "52",
    "c": "test",
    "d": "123"
}
```

But when I am not passing any of required parameters (a or b) as mentioned in oneOf and only passing c and d which are optional, it's not giving the custom error message `"either of a or b is mandatory"` instead giving the validation success and correct output. Is there a way to get the same custom error when both the required fields from oneOf are not passed?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: JSON is just data format, not able to accept passed parameters or throw errors. What kind of tools are you using, where is your code?

Comment: I am asking about json schema not json and that basically allows us to validate JSON requests and fyi we can throw custom errors using json schema when the validation fails. Please have a look at the question again.